# Difference between files skipping useless data

Tags: file, diff

let's say I have two files containing an xml, and I want to search for any difference in the files, but just looking at some tags, skipping others...

Example:

File1

```
<xml>  
 <key>key1</key>
 <value>value1</value>
 <useless_tag>something</useless_tag>
</xml>
```

File2

```
<xml>  
 <key>key1</key>
 <value>value2</value>
 <useless_tag>something_else</useless_tag>
</xml>
```

So I'd like to point out that the two files are different just because of the content in the "VALUE" tag, and not the one in the "USELESS_TAG".

I'd like to do this stuff recursively inside multilevel folders...

I'm on windows and debian...

Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks all

Comment: Anything wrong with grepping out anything you don't need, `diff File1 File2 | grep -v useless_tag`?

Comment: yes, but... It shows the "entire" File1 followed by the "entire" File2... I'd like more if it shows the disting different lines between the 2 files

Comment: I'm trying meld, it does what i need, expect for one thing: when I add a Text Filters, in the main comparison window it says that 2 files are different! And when it shows the details it says they are identical (considering the Text Filters added) ;(